# Composer installation fails : SSL handshake timeout

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

What's causing these errors? It has been like 10 times of these errors occur everytime I tried to install the composer

[image]

Note : environment variable is set up perfectly & laravel is the lastest version. (version 5 !?) , Window 7 32 bit

Thanks.

Some information gathered via `phpinfo()` about SSL

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: if u have curl installed, try this:  curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php

Comment: the result is `curl` is not recognize as internal command , & I checked via `phpinfo()` it's `enabled`.

Comment: Try to install gitbash, its default settings are much more convenient.

Answer (score 13):

Try to change `default_socket_timeout` in your php.ini to `360`.

It´s weird but, in my case it was set `default_socket_timeout = -1` and after i changed to `default_socket_timeout = 360` worked just fine.

Comment: If you use Tilde you can add code brackets to make it stand out :)

Comment: this was a long-standing bug of PHP it was fixed last summer https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62890